# Linking nodes of a particular type to each other sequentially based on a node of another type

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to link all nodes (of a type) associated with a node (different from previous nodes) to each other. I'll explain this with the help of a diagram. Given below is a dummy representation of a graph that I have created:- 
COMMAND:

```
// Movies are unique values in the dataset. 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "actors_movies.csv" AS dataset
CREATE (m:Movie{movie:dataset.name})
MERGE (a:Actor{name:dataset.actor})
MERGE (a)-[:ACTED{year:dataset.year}]->(m)
```

[image]

I want my graph to look like the following where if I query an actor, I should be able to traverse all the movies that they've acted in in a series:

[image]

I request for a query to create a graph mentioned above.

Comment: Are you asking for just relationships between movies in a series (such as John Wick, Star Wars, and The Matrix), or are you asking for relationships between movies based on the order that actors have worked on them (so if an actor only worked in one movie of a series, but wasn't in the others, having gone to work on some other movie, they would need relationships between the movies they've worked in only)

Comment: Also, in the example movies database, each :Movie has a `released` property. Can that be used instead of `year` properties on your relationships?

Comment: Hey Inverse Falcon, sorry for the late reply. Actors would need relationships between movies they have worked in. You can use the `released` property for this as what I have given is only representational. Ultimately, my requirement is to view all movies acted by a person chronologically in a graphical way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, if you only need this for the graphical results, on a per-query per-actor basis, then you may be able to use [virtual relationships](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#virtual-nodes-rels) via [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/). This will let you create fake virtual relationships that do not actually exist in the graph, but can be visualized in the graph result view. Keep in mind these only last for the duration of the query, they will not be saved to the graph, you'll need to create the virtual relationships with each query where you want to view them.

Here's an example which works for the movies graph (from `:play movies` in the neo4j browser):

```
MATCH (k:Person{name:'Keanu Reeves'})-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
WITH k, m
ORDER BY m.released ASC
WITH k, apoc.coll.pairsMin(collect(m)) as pairs // list of pairs of adjacent nodes
UNWIND pairs as pair
CALL apoc.create.vRelationship(pair[0], 'NEXT_MOVIE', {year:pair[1].released}, pair[1]) YIELD rel
RETURN k, pair[0] as m1, pair[1] as m2, rel
```

Keep in mind that if you actually want to have these saved in the graph, you're going to need a path through these movies per actor, so the relationships you create would need to have something like an `actorId` property, that way when you need to MATCH to the path of movies for an actor you would need to make sure all :NEXT_MOVIE relationships would need to have that actor's id.

That's the only way you could possibly do this in a sane way, otherwise you wouldn't know which relationships to traverse since you need to have the context of which relationship belongs to which actor.

Comment: Thanks again InverseFalcon. Looks like virtual relationships is what I needed.